# Repurposing or obtaining a cheap audio signal amplifier for school physics lab

Tags: power, amplifier, physics

I teach highschool physics, and want to connect my smartphone (LG V20) to a [Chladni plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni#Chladni_figures) (vibrating plate for studying interference patterns in sound in solids).

I have successfully done this by connecting a standard 3.5mm male-to-male lead to the phone, and crocodile clips on the other end, connected by 4mm leads to a vibration generator with the Chladni plate attached.  This works, and I can play tones and even music through the Chladni plate, and see interference patterns start to form.

However the amplitude is far below what I need.  I have a signal generator with amplifier which works well, and provides a peak output of around 6V; the speaker cable sending the same signal provides around 0.4V.

I therefore need a signal amplifier, ideally that inputs and outputs on 3.5mm or 4mm, and outputs with a variable setting up to around 20x.  I know almost nothing about electronics, and the school doesn't have a tech lab, but I do have an old [Marshall G10 Mk2 (10W guitar amplifier)](https://marshall.com/marshall-amps/products/amps/mg-gold/mg10) .  I would like some advice on how to cannibalize this speaker/amp to achieve my aims.

I did already connect these, attaining an appropriate voltage, but the quality was very poor - a lot of hissing and apparently poor connections.  I'm unsure if this is to be expected, or a sign of a problem with the amplifier.  The speaker in the Marshall is broken, but may be fixable.

Comment: Giving a specific price here probably triggered all of the close votes, but I think this question could reasonably be edited to ask about how to determine what specs are important and what *type* of product is needed. That is, assuming you do need help with those aspects and not just help finding a product and seller.

Comment: I agree with @Justin! Also, since you're actually describing an audio amplifier: Get an audio amplifier! Chances are your school has one lying around, anyway, maybe in the shape of a CD player, cassette recorder, TV, just anything that has connectors for external speakers.

Comment: Sparkfun or adafruit has some op amp devboards that could be used as amplifiiers

Comment: More likely the plate’s coil resistance is much lower than a speaker, so you may need just a current amplifier or buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everybody.  Sorry that I didn't read the rules fully enough to realise I was breaking one of them.

I'm very inexpert in electronics, I can describe it well enough for GCSE Physics but not much more!  I'll edit the question as recommended.

Also, I've just been given an old guitar amp and speaker - when I get time I intend to cannibalise it, and may well be back here to ask more specific questions as to how.

Comment: Hi @cosmogoblin - with the edits made, I voted to re-open. The guitar amplifier you linked uses an 8Ω speaker, so if the existing one is blown, you can easily replace it with another. Check your local goodwill or garage sales, etc. Make sure it's 8Ω and is rated for at least 10 watts. There are a few good videos on making your own Chladni plates, just search for "Chladni Plate DIY".

Comment: Do you know anything at all about the electrical characteristics of the "vibration generator"? Some sort of matching transformer may be required at the output of the amplifier.

Comment: Great comments, thank you everybody.  This is a when-I-have-time project, and at the moment I don't have time; but when I do, JYelton's comment will be very useful.  Dave Tweed, I don't know the electrical characteristics of the vibration generator, but I do know that the signal generator I use is recommended, so I'm basing my project on its 6V output.